# Joining dates for chart in Qlikview

Tags: qlikview

Is there any way to join all the same dates so that each bar will represent one date? I am very new in Qlikview.

Currently my barchart is as below:
[image]

Comment: Closed? You might have noticed that Stackoverflow is different from other forums. The reason is that *it is not a forum*. What you posted was a question. Underneath your question are *answers*, not posts. Read [faq]. And post your solution as an answer, otherwise you are likely to get banned if you continue use the site wrong. Btw, this is a comment. To add an answer, see the text box below

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve the problem. Apparently I have to use the Floor function to make all the dates equal.